# Triple integral of gravitational potential

Tags: calculus, integration

This question is in my homework and I'm completely stuck. I don't understand the question and have no idea to do whatsoever and how to start. I hope someone here can help me get started.

I uploaded the image of the question: [image: question]

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Use spherical coordinates $x=\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$, $z=\rho\cos\theta$ so the integral is
$$V=-2\pi Gm\delta\int_a^b d\rho\ \int_0^\pi d\theta\frac{\rho^2\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\rho^2\sin^2\theta+(r-\rho\cos\theta)^2}}.$$
Expand the stuff in the radical and make the natural substitution in order to complete the $\theta$ integral. This gives
$$V=-2\pi Gm\delta\int_a^b d\rho\ \frac{\rho}{r}\left(\sqrt{(r+\rho)^2}-\sqrt{(r-\rho)^2}\right).$$
Here is where the assumption $r>b>\rho$ comes into play: $|r-\rho|=r-\rho$, so
$$V=-\frac{2\pi Gm\delta}{r}\int_a^b d\rho\ 2\rho^2=-\frac{4\pi Gm\delta}{3r}\left(b^3-a^3\right).$$
Finally, the assumption of uniform density means that
$$\delta=M/(\textrm{total volume})=\frac{3M}{4\pi(b^3-a^3)}.$$